# Elasticsearch error with JanusGraph

Tags: elasticsearch, janusgraph

It looks like I am hitting a problem with elasticsearch even though I do not have this configured anywhere :(

Application code (Java):

```java
public static void main(String args[]) {
    JanusGraph g = JanusGraphFactory.open("/path/to/file/janusgraph-solr.properties");
    GraphOfTheGodsFactory.load(g);
    g.close();
}
```

Configuration (`janushgraph-solr.properties`):

```
# Change to the directory where JanusGraph was extracted.  Later commands
# use relative paths to the Solr config files shipped with the JanusGraph
# distribution.
cd $JANUSGRAPH_HOME

# The name must be URL safe and should contain one dot/full-stop
# character. The part of the name after the dot must not conflict with
# any of JanusGraph's internal CF names.  Starting the part after the dot
# "solr" will avoid a conflict with JanusGraph's internal CF names.
CORE_NAME=testt
# Where to upload collection configuration and send CoreAdmin requests.
SOLR_HOST=localhost:8983

# The value of index.[X].solr.http-urls in JanusGraph's config file
# should match $SOLR_HOST and $CORE_NAME.  For example, given the
# $CORE_NAME and $SOLR_HOST values above, JanusGraph's config file would
# contain (assuming "search" is the desired index alias):
#
 index.search.solr.http-urls=http://localhost:8983/solr/testt
#
# The stock JanusGraph config file conf/janusgraph-cassandra-solr.properties
# ships with this http-urls value.

storage.backend=cassandrathrift
```

For reference, here's the [GraphOfTheGods file](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/blob/master/janusgraph-core/src/main/java/org/janusgraph/example/GraphOfTheGodsFactory.java).

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate implementation: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.es.ElasticSearchIndex
    at org.janusgraph.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:69)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:477)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend.getIndexes(Backend.java:464)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend.<init>(Backend.java:149)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.getBackend(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1850)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.StandardJanusGraph.<init>(StandardJanusGraph.java:134)
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:107)
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:75)
    at graph.red_graph.App.main(App.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.janusgraph.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:58)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: []
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:279)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:198)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.InternalTransportClusterAdminClient.execute(InternalTransportClusterAdminClient.java:86)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClusterAdminClient.health(AbstractClusterAdminClient.java:127)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.cluster.health.ClusterHealthRequestBuilder.doExecute(ClusterHealthRequestBuilder.java:92)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:91)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:65)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.es.ElasticSearchIndex.<init>(ElasticSearchIndex.java:215)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: You are using `GraphOfTheGodsFactory`, that uses elastic search as index backend

Comment: If you want a default schema just copy paste the schema from this line https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/blob/master/janusgraph-core/src/main/java/org/janusgraph/example/GraphOfTheGodsFactory.java#L79

Comment: And also remove the line `GraphOfTheGodsFactory.load(g);` from your code

Comment: @AshrafulIslam okay I tried using the schema from the link you mentioned, i still see elastic search as the index. is there anyway to use solr instead? is there a simple example instead of GraphOfTheGodsFactory that uses solr?

Comment: @AshrafulIslam i still see this exception Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate implementation: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.es.ElasticSearchIndex with the schema at the link you mentioned

Comment: @AshrafulIslam if i could see a simple solr example that would be great

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using JanusGraph with Solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46545611/using-janusgraph-with-solr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**GraphOfTheGodsFactory uses elastic search as index backend**

So If you want a sample schema just use the below schema

```
JanusGraph graph = JanusGraphFactory.open("/path/to/file/janusgraph-solr.properties");
String mixedIndexName = "search"; //Your Solr Collection/Core Name
boolean uniqueNameCompositeIndex = true;

JanusGraphManagement mgmt = graph.openManagement();
final PropertyKey name = mgmt.makePropertyKey("name").dataType(String.class).make();
JanusGraphManagement.IndexBuilder nameIndexBuilder = mgmt.buildIndex("name", Vertex.class).addKey(name);
if (uniqueNameCompositeIndex)
    nameIndexBuilder.unique();
JanusGraphIndex namei = nameIndexBuilder.buildCompositeIndex();
mgmt.setConsistency(namei, ConsistencyModifier.LOCK);
final PropertyKey age = mgmt.makePropertyKey("age").dataType(Integer.class).make();
if (null != mixedIndexName)
    mgmt.buildIndex("vertices", Vertex.class).addKey(age).buildMixedIndex(mixedIndexName);

final PropertyKey time = mgmt.makePropertyKey("time").dataType(Integer.class).make();
final PropertyKey reason = mgmt.makePropertyKey("reason").dataType(String.class).make();
final PropertyKey place = mgmt.makePropertyKey("place").dataType(Geoshape.class).make();
if (null != mixedIndexName)
    mgmt.buildIndex("edges", Edge.class).addKey(reason).addKey(place).buildMixedIndex(mixedIndexName);

mgmt.makeEdgeLabel("father").multiplicity(Multiplicity.MANY2ONE).make();
mgmt.makeEdgeLabel("mother").multiplicity(Multiplicity.MANY2ONE).make();
EdgeLabel battled = mgmt.makeEdgeLabel("battled").signature(time).make();
mgmt.buildEdgeIndex(battled, "battlesByTime", Direction.BOTH, Order.decr, time);
mgmt.makeEdgeLabel("lives").signature(reason).make();
mgmt.makeEdgeLabel("pet").make();
mgmt.makeEdgeLabel("brother").make();

mgmt.makeVertexLabel("titan").make();
mgmt.makeVertexLabel("location").make();
mgmt.makeVertexLabel("god").make();
mgmt.makeVertexLabel("demigod").make();
mgmt.makeVertexLabel("human").make();
mgmt.makeVertexLabel("monster").make();

mgmt.commit();

JanusGraphTransaction tx = graph.newTransaction();
// vertices

Vertex saturn = tx.addVertex(T.label, "titan", "name", "saturn", "age", 10000);
Vertex sky = tx.addVertex(T.label, "location", "name", "sky");
Vertex sea = tx.addVertex(T.label, "location", "name", "sea");
Vertex jupiter = tx.addVertex(T.label, "god", "name", "jupiter", "age", 5000);
Vertex neptune = tx.addVertex(T.label, "god", "name", "neptune", "age", 4500);
Vertex hercules = tx.addVertex(T.label, "demigod", "name", "hercules", "age", 30);
Vertex alcmene = tx.addVertex(T.label, "human", "name", "alcmene", "age", 45);
Vertex pluto = tx.addVertex(T.label, "god", "name", "pluto", "age", 4000);
Vertex nemean = tx.addVertex(T.label, "monster", "name", "nemean");
Vertex hydra = tx.addVertex(T.label, "monster", "name", "hydra");
Vertex cerberus = tx.addVertex(T.label, "monster", "name", "cerberus");
Vertex tartarus = tx.addVertex(T.label, "location", "name", "tartarus");

// edges

jupiter.addEdge("father", saturn);
jupiter.addEdge("lives", sky, "reason", "loves fresh breezes");
jupiter.addEdge("brother", neptune);
jupiter.addEdge("brother", pluto);

neptune.addEdge("lives", sea).property("reason", "loves waves");
neptune.addEdge("brother", jupiter);
neptune.addEdge("brother", pluto);

hercules.addEdge("father", jupiter);
hercules.addEdge("mother", alcmene);
hercules.addEdge("battled", nemean, "time", 1, "place", Geoshape.point(38.1f, 23.7f));
hercules.addEdge("battled", hydra, "time", 2, "place", Geoshape.point(37.7f, 23.9f));
hercules.addEdge("battled", cerberus, "time", 12, "place", Geoshape.point(39f, 22f));

pluto.addEdge("brother", jupiter);
pluto.addEdge("brother", neptune);
pluto.addEdge("lives", tartarus, "reason", "no fear of death");
pluto.addEdge("pet", cerberus);

cerberus.addEdge("lives", tartarus);

// commit the transaction to disk
tx.commit();
```

*Note : Here mixedIndexName = "search" is Your Solr Collection/Core Name*

Sample Index Backend Config file :

```
index.search.backend=solr
index.search.index-name=search
index.search.solr.mode=http
index.search.solr.http-urls=http://192.168.18.12:8983/solr
```

Comment: hm.. looks like this is still using eleasticsearch? i still get the following exception: 00:46:11,187  INFO ElasticSearchIndex:368 - Configured remote host: 127.0.0.1 : 9300
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate implementation: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.es.ElasticSearchIndex

Comment: So in the sample config i still need to specify the storage.backend=cassandrathrift ...? Without this i get an error that the backend needs to be specified

Comment: If i add the storage.backend=cassandrathrift i get the same exception about elasticsearch

Comment: @BigBug also remove existing janusgraph data from cassandra. Because It's previously used elasticsearch it's keeping the previous config

Comment: Easy way to remove the cassandra data is to, stop janusgraph and drop the keyspace of janusgraph and start again

Comment: Hm... i don't see anything in cassandra, no keyspace was created :(

Answer (score 1):

I could reproduce this error when I was migrating from Janus v0.1.1 to v0.2.0 Earlier with v0.1.1 I was using cassandra+ES. With v0.2.0 I wanted to to run cassandra+Solr. Even though in the config file there was no mention of ES, I was still getting node not available error.

I removed the meta data of cassandra, dropped the keyspace and the db folder. And started solr and Cassandra from scratch. This seemed to solve my problem. I believe cassandra was expecting ES for indexing, hence the need to clear it up.

Answer (score 0):

Simply delete tables system_properties AND system_properties_lock_ in schema used by janusgraph to force reinitialization of configuration